# Vitamio error ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-studio, media-player, android-mediaplayer

After many attempts and all kinds of tests, I managed to make it work vitamio. But now I have a problem. Fail to do ProgressBar.
Please help. I keep getting errors, android studio.

```
public class KanalD extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private String path;
//private HashMap<String, String> options;
private VideoView mVideoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vitamio_videoView);
    path = "http://80.86.107.169:8100/stream.flv";
    /*options = new HashMap<>();
    options.put("rtmp_playpath", "");
    options.put("rtmp_swfurl", "");
    options.put("rtmp_live", "1");
    options.put("rtmp_pageurl", "");*/
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
    //mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path), options);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
            myProgressBar = (myProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.Gone);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

And, the XML part:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: Error:(47, 17) error: cannot find symbol variable myProgressBar

Comment: Error:(48, 49) error: cannot find symbol variable Gone

Comment: Please add the whole layout of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there is no variable declaration for `myProgressBar`

replace

```
myProgressBar = (myProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
```

with

```
final ProgressBar myProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
```

However, I don't see what could be wrong with `myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.Gone);`, if `myProgressBar` is declared properly.

Comment: I replaced, like you  said, but remains in progressbar and not charging

Comment: mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
                final ProgressBar myProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            }
        });

Comment: Well, why do you set *visibility* to `View.Gone`? That would remove the progress bar from the view hierarchy. If you want to show the progress bar, you would have to set *visibility* to `View.Visible`.